# Dynamic Control Positioning

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, dynamic, controls

I'm trying to dynamically position controls on a page, I've got the hang of "wrapping" the controls to the next line when the width is smaller than the total width of the controls.
The problem I'm having now, is getting the spacing correct.

I currently have the following;

```
 public void AddControl(Control controlToAdd, int parentWidth, int allRowsHeight)
 {
     RowControls.Add(controlToAdd);

     int seperationWidth = (parentWidth - RowControls.Sum(c => c.Width)) / (RowControls.Count + 1);
     int count = 0;
     foreach (Control c in RowControls)
     {
         int xLocation = (seperationWidth*(count+1));
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         {
             xLocation += (RowControls[i].Width);
         }
         c.Location = new Point(xLocation, allRowsHeight);
         count++;
     }
 }
```

This ***almost*** works, but as you can see from the screenshot, the controls are going a bit too far and I'm not quite sure why that is?
The "wrapping" check is basically a repetition of the `seperationWidth` line, it ensures of minimum spacing of 1, i.e if the spacing is less than 1, it "wraps" instead.

Perhaps there's a completely different and better way to do this? I do have access to DevExpress too if anyone is familiar with that.

**EDIT:**
Suspect my method has an issue with rounding. Not sure how I can get around it though;
In this instance, `seperationWidth` is 7 and the control widths are 128.
7+128+7+128+7+128+7+128+7=547.
Not sure how I can get around this issue though?

[image: Example]

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're not just using a FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: Will that automatically layout the controls like I'm trying to do, when I add them programmatically?

Comment: Why would I have mentioned it if it didn't.  Read the MSDN documentation for the class, which should be the first thing you do when pointed towards a new type or member.

Comment: That's a start. Can't see any options to make it center controls though. I get this; http://imgur.com/i1ETkas but I want this; http://imgur.com/3tpfHli

Comment: Hmmm... to be honest I've never used a FLP myself but I'd not expect that it could do that.

Comment: I made an edit, I think the issue may be to do with rounding, not sure if you've got any suggestions on ways to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the issue here was that I was passing the `Width` property into the `parentWidth` parameter. What I actually needed to do was pass the `ClientSize.Width` property. This fixed the issue, buttons are now laid out correctly.